# Stop being asked for permission each time user login with twitter account in my app

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using febric for android twitter integration, and  I could successfully login from Twitter native App to my app. But it always asks user to allow sharing account details.

Below are the screen

[image]

After i allow another screen comes

[image]

Why it asks for allow each time user login with same account, since it should be asked only for (the first) one time for each user? How can I solve it?

Comment: did you get the solution for this?? @jeetu

Comment: @Tanveer Not now But for help you have to read Twitter developer doc, this pop may appear each time.

Comment: check BUNDLE app, it just takes one time login credentials and permissions

Comment: even thought it's been a year... have you found any solution for this problem?